# in ef core combine nullable columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

now,i use  EF core to search database,with this code

```
.Select(i => new { id = "" + i.OrganID, name = i.OrganName + "_" + i.LeaderMobile  })
```

the column named LeaderMobile is nullable,   `nvarchar(100) null`.

when `OrganName` is not null and  `LeaderMobile` is null,  the result is null.

excample:

OrganName="aaa"  LeaderMobile =null

The result is null,
but I want the result is "aaa_" ( in EF ,it does work)

How can i do without change this code. well, I mean where i can config to make it work.

Not like:

```
.Select(i => new { id = "" + i.OrganID, name = i.OrganName + "_" + (i.LeaderMobile ?? "") })
```

Comment: I think you can do this in model class for  `set` of `LeaderMobile`and assign empty string if this member is `null`.

Comment: @vivek nuna thank you for comment. but this is not i wanted. the database is running.  And it has a lot of tables and columns. I want to update my project with transformation  as small as possible

Comment: you can create an abstract class with this property and inherit the model classes from it.

Comment: @vivek nuna  Well,maybe i need to get a program to replace the code ?!